# Getting their name based on 2 columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013 with VBA.
I have a ComboBox that allows me to choose RestDays `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, and so on.
If I choose `Mon`, I want all agents that has RD on Monday to display in the ListBox.  In the example I can display it but it only refers to single column, I want to be able to also use the other column.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmbRestDay_Change()
    Dim x, dict
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set mySheet = Sheets("Dashboard")
    ListBox1.Clear
    x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns(2), cmbRestDay.Value) > 0 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
            If x(i, 2) = cmbRestDay.Value Then
                dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        ListBox1.List = dict.keys
    Else
        ListBox1.AddItem "Match not found"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cmbRestDay.Clear
    With cmbRestDay
        .AddItem ("Mon")
        .AddItem ("Tue")
        .AddItem ("Wed")
        .AddItem ("Thu")
        .AddItem ("Fri")
        .AddItem ("Sat")
        .AddItem ("Sun")
    End With

    cmbMyRD.Clear
    With cmbMyRD
        .AddItem ("Mon")
        .AddItem ("Tue")
        .AddItem ("Wed")
        .AddItem ("Thu")
        .AddItem ("Fri")
        .AddItem ("Sat")
        .AddItem ("Sun")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Or` logical operator:

```
If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns("B:C"), cmbRestDay.Value) > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(i, 2) = cmbRestDay.Value Or x(i, 3) = cmbRestDay.Value Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much YowE3K..that is working now ..I will have to focus on the codes that somes unfamiliar for me now like the UBound.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmbRestDay_Change()
    Dim x As Integer

    Set mySheet = Sheets("Dashboard")
    ListBox1.Clear

    If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Range("A:B"), "*" & cmbRestDay.Value & "*") > 0 Then
        For x = 2 To Application.CountA(mySheet.Columns(1))
            If mySheet.Cells(x, 2) = cmbRestDay.Value Or mySheet.Cells(x, 3) = cmbRestDay.Value Then
                ListBox1.AddItem (mySheet.Cells(x, 1))
            End If
        Next
    Else
        ListBox1.AddItem ("Match not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should never use `Interger` if you can use `Long` (Excel has more rows than integer can handle). And you should declare `mySheet As Worksheet`. I recommend to [always use `Option Explicit`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).